# Which version of JasperReports is supported by ZK v6.5.8?

Tags: jasper-reports, zk

What is the latest version of JasperReports supported by ZK v6.5.8?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Please have a look this

http://books.zkoss.org/wiki/Small_Talks/2012/April/Create_a_Report_with_ZK_using_iReport_and_JasperReports

The already mentioned

Version

```
ZK 5/6, iReport 4.5.0, JasperReports 4.5.0
```

Now check this link

http://emrpms.blogspot.in/2013/09/create-report-with-zk-using-ireport-510.html

Its using some higher version with `zk6.5`

But remember Jasper Report is only available of `Zk EE`